# Set-Cookie not setting cookies in production

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, vercel

I'm using React with Axios for the web client and Django REST Framework for the API.

`csrftoken` and `sessionid` cookies are set when in local development, also in Postman using the API in production. But in my Vercel React app, the cookies aren't set although the request was successful.

**`settings.py`**

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    # web client url,
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000', 
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    # web client url,
)

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000', 
    'http://localhost:8000', 
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    # web client url,
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    "accept",
    "accept-encoding",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "dnt",
    "origin",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
]

CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = [
  "Content-Type", 
  "X-CSRFToken"
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "csrftoken"

CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'

SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

**Axios configs:**

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

const axiosClient = axios.create({
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken',
  xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

axiosClient.defaults.baseURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? apiUrls.PROD_ROOT
  : apiUrls.DEV_ROOT;

export default axiosClient;
```

**Response in Vercel App:**
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YavT1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add " withCredentials: true" to your Axios , this should solve your problem

Comment: Did you mean this?
const axiosClient = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken',
  xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});